# Ajax + Cherrypy login

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to program a forum in python(with cherrypy). And i would like to use Ajax. There are 2 Buttons like [Login] and [Registration]. When the user push the the Registration button he should type a id and a password. And all the informations are going to a json file. The problem is i do not know how to start. can anybody please help me

Comment: We could do with a little more information - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - what problems are you having so far?

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil when the user push the button registration he has to type his id and password. And i red in a forum that i have to do it with the -Post- command. But how do i save it in a json file?